# Precise Throughput Timer stuck with simple setup

Tags: multithreading, timer, jmeter

I have a similar issue as [Synchronizing timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186375/jmeter-test-hangs-on-using-synchronizing-timer) hangs with simple setup, but with [Precise Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) which suppose to replace Synchronizing timer:

> Certain cases might be solved via Synchronizing Timer, however Precise Throughput Timer has native way to issue requests in packs. This behavior is disabled by default, and it is controlled with "Batched departures" settings
>
> Number of threads in the batch (threads). Specifies the number of samples in a batch. Note the overall number of samples will still be in line with Target Throughput
>   Delay between threads in the batch (ms). For instance, if set to 42, and the batch size is 3, then threads will depart at x, x+42ms, x+84ms

I'm setting 10 thread number , 1 ramp up and 1 loop count,

I'm adding 1 HTTP Request only (less than 1 seconds response) and before it Test Action with Precise Throughput Timer as a child with the following setup:

[image]

Thread stuck after 5 threads succeeded:

[image]
**EDIT 1**

According to @Dimitri T solution:
Change Duration to 100 and add line to logging configuration and got 5 errors:

```
2018-03-12 15:43:42,330 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping Thread: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: The thread is scheduled to stop in -99886 ms and the throughput timer generates a delay of 20004077. JMeter (as of 4.0) does not support interrupting of sleeping threads, thus terminating the thread manually.
```

**EDIT 2**

According to @Dimitri T solution set "Loop Count" to -1 executed 10 threads, but if I change `Number of threads in batch` from 2 to 5 it execute only 3 threads and stops

```
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping Thread: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: The thread is scheduled to stop in -89233 ms and the throughput timer generates a delay of 19999450. JMeter (as of 4.0) does not support interrupting of sleeping threads, thus terminating the thread manually.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set "Duration (seconds)" in your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to something non-zero (i.e. to `100`)
2. Depending on what you're trying to achieve you might also want to set "Loop Count" to `-1`

   [image: JMeter Thread Group Configuration]

You can also add the following line to [*log4j2.xml* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging):

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.timers" level="debug" />
```

This way you will be able to see what's going on with your timer(s) in *jmeter.log* file

[image: JMeter Timers Log]

Comment: I must set `Duration`?  Also I'm getting only 5 threads submitted. add errors in question

Comment: `throughput timer generates a delay of 20004077`. Just wait for 6 hours and it will complete, otherwise go for recommendation from point 2

Comment: It may work, but if I change `Number of threads in batch` from 2 to 5 it execute only 3 threads and stops `INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping Thread: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: The thread is scheduled to stop in -89233 ms and the throughput timer generates a delay of 19999450. JMeter (as of 4.0) does not support interrupting of sleeping threads, thus terminating the thread manually.`